# What are Distance Regular Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have been trying to understand distance regular graphs and how to compute the intersection array.

[Distance Regular Graphs](http://buzzard.ups.edu/courses/2007spring/projects/paauwe-paper-revised.pdf), this is the resource I have used. I could not figure what is br in δ(v,u)=r.br

Secondly cr in cr is the number of vertices that are adjacent to u and a distance of r − 1 from v

Lastly the two clauses for intersection array in the given link.

​
P.S : I need its concept to understand a paper, would appreciate the help

Comment: The author is violating an important tenet of mathematical writing: *Never start a sentence with a symbol.* In the last paragraph of page 3, one sentence reads "Distance regular graphs have an *intersection array* [...] where for any two vertices $v$ and $u$ that are $r$ distance apart, $\delta(v,u) = r$." (This seems to be the author's way of *defining* $\delta$, although the phrasing could be better.) The immediately-following $b_r$ is the start of the next sentence, it is not being multiplied by the $r$. Does that help?

Comment: Yes thanks! a silly misunderstanding anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the paper, with some hopefully helpful comments in red.

> Distance regular graphs have an intersection array $\{b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_{d−1};c_1,c_2, \ldots,c_d\}$ where for any two vertices $v$ and $u$ that are $r$ distance apart, $δ(v,u) = r$.$\color{red}{\leftarrow \text{a period.}}$ $b_r$ is the number of vertices that are adjacent to $u$ and at a distance $r + 1$ to $v$.$\color{red}{\leftarrow \text{another period.}}$ $c_r$ is the number of vertices that are adjacent to $u$ and a distance of $r − 1$ from $v$.

The definition should be clear now.

Comment: yes i got it now but what the entries of intersection array represent? Are those the number of vertices adjacent to you I am assuming 
$$b_{0} , b_{1},...,b_{d-1} = b_{r}$$

Comment: $d$ is the dimension of the graph. Thus the entries of the "intersection array" are the successive values of the $b_r$'s ($0 \leqslant r  \leqslant d-1$) followed by the successive values of the $c_r$'s ($1 \leqslant r  \leqslant d$).